# Simplifying low-rank matrix completion using SDP

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, matrix-completion

I understand that a Low-Rank Matrix Completion (LRMC) problem of the form:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{X}} \mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{X}) \\
\text{s.t.:} \quad \mathbf{X}_{i,j} = \mathbf{M}_{i,j} \quad \forall (i,j) \in \Omega, 
$$

where $\Omega$ is the set of indices of observed entries, can be posed as a Semidefinite Programming (SDP):
$$
\min_{\mathbf{Y}} \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{Y}) \\
\text{s.t.:} \quad \langle \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{A}_k \rangle = b_k, \quad \forall k \in [1, |\Omega|], \\
\mathbf{Y} \succeq 0
$$

where $\mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{S}_1 & \mathbf{X} \\ \mathbf{X}^{\top} & \mathbf{S}_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n_1 + n_2) \times (n_1 + n_2)}$ and $\mathbf{A}_k$ and $b_k$ are suitable sampling matrices and observed entries respectively.

However, if in the problem formulation, it is guaranteed that the matrix we are searching for ($\mathbf{X}$) necessarily:

1. admits a solution such that $\mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{X}) = 1$,
2. $\mathbf{X}$ is square and symmetric matrix,
3. $\mathbf{X}$ can be expressed as $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{v}$ for some $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n$ and consequently,
4. a positive semi-definite matrix in itself,

can we not simplify the SDP for LRMC as:
$$ \min_{\mathbf{X}} \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{X}) \\
\text{s.t.:} \quad \mathbf{X}_{i,j} = \mathbf{M}_{i,j} \quad \forall (i,j) \in \Omega, \\
\mathbf{X} \succeq 0
$$
given sufficient entries in $\Omega$ and assuming noise-free data?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The LRMC is in general formulated for rectangular matrices. What does it mean "positive semidefinite" for a rectangular matrix?

Comment: @Exodd assuming X is a square matrix of course. Is the LRMC for square matrices different from non-square matrices? I am new to this field, so if that is the case, please point it out.

Comment: not really, but then you also have to assume $X$ is symmetric

Comment: yes to that, X being symmetric is also given. In fact, $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{v}$ for some vector $\mathbf{v}$ whose elements are real and positive, but I do not want to parameterize with $\mathbf{v}$ directly

Comment: In this case yes, you can rewrite the problem in this fashion. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3286.pdf), for example

Comment: @Exodd thanks for the clarification